# How to get list of a json object

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Hello everyone i am stuck to figure out the response from api tried to get the list of object and print in debug but I am failed to do it i think i am missing something

I want to get list of these words but i don't know how to do it any guide ?

```
alanin, alaunian, alnein, alnuin, eolienne, laniinae, lanny, lenaean, lenin, lenny, lennow, leonine, lewanna, linen, linene, lineny, linin, linn, linnaea, linne, linon, lionne, loanin, lunn
```

I am using Flutter and http package and tried dio too

here is my code and response

```
Future<List> onBtnPress(String text) async {
  http.Response response = await http.post(url, body: body);
  return jsonDecode(response.body);
```

}

```
List _data = await onBtnPress(textController.text);
     debugPrint(_data.toList().toString());



[522, [alanin, alaunian, alnein, alnuin, eolienne, laniinae, lanny, lenaean, lenin, lenny, lennow, leonine, lewanna, linen, linene, lineny, linin, linn, linnaea, linne, linon, lionne, loanin, lunn], 373, [macoma, mecum, myokymia, mokum]]
```

I tried `_data[0][index]` but it show only 5 2 2

Comment: Use model class to get response

Answer (score 1):

create a response model using [this](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)

```
Future<listResponse> getList() async {
    final HttpResponse response = await this.getRequest(ApiType.getObjectList, params: {}, );
    responseList objData;
    if (response.status == 200 ) {
      objData = responseList.fromJson(response.json);
      return listResponse(status: response.status, message: response.errMessage, data: objData);
    }else{
      return listResponse(status: response.status, message: response.errMessage, data: null);
    }
  }
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

```
var rawJson = '{"url":"http://blah.jpg","id":1}';
Map<String,dynamic> parsedJson   = json.decode(rawJson);
var imageModel = ImageModel(id: parsedJson['id'],url: parsedJson['url']);

class ImageModel
{ int id; String url; ImageModel({this.id,this.url});}
```

Comment: before converting your json response into the list object , you have to convert that responce into json.decode(response)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have already did convert jsonDecode(response.body) i am getting list, my question is how do i get the list inside object like i have [523, [ asdf, asdf, asdf ] ,233, [ asdf ,adsf ,adsf ,asdf ] ], what i want to get the list [asdf,adsf,asdf,afd]

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23988797)

Answer (score 0):

Your are using POST method instead of Get. That's why you are fetching the status code.
Try,

`Future<List> onBtnPress(String text) async {
  http.Response response = await http.get(url, body: body);
  return jsonDecode(response.body);`

Also if authentication is required ensure to add it in headers

Comment: Thanks for your answer i solved that problem can you tell what should i pass in header ? i will update firebase cloud function code for authentication.

Comment: waiting for your answer

Comment: `{
       'Content-type': 'application/json',
       'Accept': 'application/json',
       'Authorization': '<Your token>'
     }`

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out guys thanks
response i am getting is a list

its like list[0] = 522; list[1] = [asdf,adsf,asdf,]

Thank you very much

```
data[0] = 522
```

&

```
data[1] = [alanin, alaunian, alnein, alnuin, eolienne, laniinae, lanny, lenaean, lenin, lenny, lennow, leonine, lewanna, linen, linene, lineny, linin, linn, linnaea, linne, linon, lionne, loanin, lunn]
```